# Calculate the storage periods based on inbound and outbound quantity

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a Google sheets file to keep track of storage period.

Here's the example of my logic:

**Day 1: 10 pieces are inbounded** ===> storage period is counted from Day 1;

**Day 5: 5 pieces are outbounded** ===> storage period is still counted from Day 1;

**Day 8: 10 more pieces are inbounded** ===> storage period is still counted from Day 1;

**Day 10: 8 pieces are outbounded.**

===> With this outbound, the total amount exceed the first inbound (13>10) ===> storage period is counted from Day 8 of the 2nd inbound instead of Day 1 of the 1st.

**Day 12: 1 piece is outbounded** ===> storage period is still counted from Day 8.

How can I write a formula to make this work?

Dummy data follows:

| Date | SKU | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | In | 10 |
| 5 | ABC | Out | 5 |
| 8 | ABC | In | 10 |
| 10 | ABC | Out | 8 |
| 12 | ABC | Out | 1 |

Comment: Don't you mean that Date `10` 5 out of 8 have storage from date `1` and the remainder (3) has storage from date `8`?

Comment: That's right sir

Comment: Your logic says differently. Does my answer still meet your requirements then?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question somehow, and my fault also for not stating clearly the result I want.

The dummy data is the data only. The result I want would be another sheet with just [SKU name], [stock available until now] and [storage time].

The one I'm asking is how to calculate the [storage time] using the logic I posted.

Given the dummy data, the result would be the item [ABC] until Date 12 having the [stock of 6] with the storage time being from Date 8 to Date 12 = 4 days.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly and make sure to properly state how you expect the result to show (and why). Could there be multiple SKU's within the same list? Do you want the result for one specific?

Answer (score 1):

As commented I doubt the logic you want to show is what you really need, but this formula will get you the result (in Excel, as tagged):

```
=LET(c,   C2:C6,
     a,   TOROW(c)="Out",
     b,   TOROW(ROW(c))<=ROW(c),
     in,  MMULT(NOT(a)*b,D2:D6),
     out, MMULT(a*b,D2:D6),
IF(TOCOL(a),
   XLOOKUP(out,
           in,
           A2:A6,
           ,
           1),
   ""))
```

`in` and `out` calculate the running count of inbound / outbound transactions separately and stores these as an array.

These arrays are used to lookup the matching or first smaller match to `out` within `in` and return the date.

In the screenshot below I added the `in` and `out` array-results in column E & F for illustration:

[image]

Maybe this is what you mean to get from the updated info:

```
=LET(sku, "ABC",
   range, A2:D7,
       c, INDEX(range,,3),
       a, TOROW(c)="Out",
       b, TOROW(ROW(c))<=ROW(c),
       d, TOROW(INDEX(range,,2))=sku,
      in, MMULT(NOT(a)*b*d,INDEX(range,,4)),
     out, MMULT(a*b*d,INDEX(range,,4)),
VSTACK({"SKU","Stock available","Oldest stock date"},
       HSTACK(sku,
              TAKE(in,-1)- 
              TAKE(out,-1),                          
              XLOOKUP(TAKE(out,-1),
                      in,
                      INDEX(range,,1),
                      ,
                      1))))
```

Or for multiple SKU's:

```
=LET(range, A2:D7,
 VSTACK({"SKU","Stock available","Oldest stock date"},
 DROP(
      REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(INDEX(range,,2)),
      LAMBDA(x,sku,
         LET(c, INDEX(range,,3),
             a, TOROW(c)="Out",       
             b, TOROW(ROW(c))<=ROW(c),
             d, TOROW(INDEX(range,,2))=sku,
            in, MMULT(NOT(a)*b*d,INDEX(range,,4)),
           out, MMULT(a*b*d,INDEX(range,,4)),
VSTACK(x,
       HSTACK(sku,
              TAKE(in,-1)-TAKE(out,-1),
              XLOOKUP(TAKE(out,-1),
                      in,
                      INDEX(range,,1),
                      ,
                      1)))))),
      1)))
```

[image]